# Adding Facebook Buttons from the Facebook website on to a WordPress Site

Tags: java, javascript, php, facebook, wordpress

I am trying to add a Facebook Like button from the Facebook page.  When I create the code to be added into my posts and pages, there are only two ways to do that.  One is by adding some java script into the body tag and then placing the rest of the code where I want to display the buttons.  Since I am using a WordPress template, I do not see anywhere where I am able to place any code into the body tag.  The other option is placing an iFrame code into the page or post where I want the buttons to appear.  Neither of these options work, so not sure what to do from here.  Can anyone explain this in easy terms?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your post it sounds like you're not a coder - which is fine!  :-)  But in that case you might find it easier to use any of the wordpress plugins for adding an FB like.  For example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-button-plugin/